# How to rewrite this in terms of R.compose

Tags: ramda.js

```
var take = R.curry(function take(count, o) {
    return R.pick(R.take(count, R.keys(o)), o);
});
```

This function takes `count` keys from an object, in the order, in which they appear. I use it to limit a dataset which was grouped.

I understand that there are placeholder arguments, like `R.__`, but I can't wrap my head around this particular case.

Comment: A more straightforward approach is to work with pairs: `R.compose(R.fromPairs, R.take(count), R.toPairs)`.

Comment: So now I have something like `var take = R.curry((count, obj) => R.compose(R.fromPairs, R.take(count), R.toPairs)(obj));`
Where I still have to wire the object through, if I want to avoid the take(5)(obj) syntax. Any tips about that?

Comment: @davidchambers, I guess I need a generic way, of providing a parameter to an inner function, without wrapping it in a function explicitly...

Answer (score 1):

This is possible thanks to [`R.converge`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#converge), but I don't recommend going point-free in this case.

```
//  take :: Number -> Object -> Object
var take = R.curryN(2,
                    R.converge(R.pick,
                               R.converge(R.take,
                                          R.nthArg(0),
                                          R.pipe(R.nthArg(1),
                                                 R.keys)),
                               R.nthArg(1)));
```

One thing to note is that the behaviour of this function is undefined since the order of the list returned by `R.keys` is undefined.

Comment: Whoa. That's quite complex and does not minimize anything :)
Also, i'm aware of the ordering ambiguity, but it's acceptable for my use case.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @davidchambers that it is probably better not to do this points-free.  This solution is a bit cleaner than  that one, but is still not to my mind as nice as your original:

```
// take :: Number -> Object -> Object
var take = R.converge(
    R.pick, 
    R.useWith(R.take, R.identity, R.keys), 
    R.nthArg(1)
);
```

`useWith` and `converge` are similar in that they accept a number of function parameters and pass the result of calling all but the first one into that first one.  The difference is that `converge` passes all the parameters it receives to each one, and `useWith` splits them up, passing one to each function.  This is the first time I've seen a use for combining them, but it seems to make sense here.

That property ordering issue is supposed to be resolved in ES6 ([final draft](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:specification_drafts#final_draft) now out!) but it's [still controversial](https://mail.mozilla.org/pipermail/es-discuss/2015-April/042508.html).

---

### Update

You mention that it will take some time to figure this out.  This should help at least show how it's equivalent to your original function, if not how to derive it:

```
var take = R.converge(
    R.pick, 
    R.useWith(R.take, R.identity, R.keys), 
    R.nthArg(1)
);
    // definition of `converge`
(count, obj) => R.pick(R.useWith(R.take, R.identity, R.keys)(count, obj), 
        R.nthArg(1)(count, obj));
    // definition of `nthArg`
(count, obj) => R.pick(R.useWith(R.take, R.identity, R.keys)(count, obj), obj);
    // definition of `useWith`
(count, obj) => R.pick(R.take(R.identity(count), R.keys(obj)), obj);
    // definition of `identity`
(count, obj) => R.pick(R.take(count, R.keys(obj)), obj);
```

---

### Update 2

As of [version 18](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/issues/1436), both `converge` and `useWith` have changed to become binary.  Each takes a target function and a list of helper functions.  That would change the above slightly to this:

```
// take :: Number -> Object -> Object
var take = R.converge(R.pick, [
    R.useWith(R.take, [R.identity, R.keys]), 
    R.nthArg(1)
]);
```

Comment: It'll take some time to figure it out :)

Comment: @VasiliSviridov: Added some explanation

Comment: "That property ordering issue is supposed to be resolved in ES6" -- Unfortunately the proposed resolution is non-deterministic, since it relies upon key insertion order. So `keys({a: 1, b: 2}) =/= keys({b:2, a: 1})`