# Ramda help: Pointfree implementation w/ placeholders to direct arguments

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, currying, ramda.js

This is my first go around with ramda. I'm trying to create a map function that automatically adds a key each object in an array. Would be helpful for react stateless functions, for instance, where we might have a function with a signature

```
 ({ prop1, prop2, key }) => ...
```

and an array of

```
 [{ prop1: 'prop one', prop2: 'prop two' }, {...etc}]
```

Here's a working example:

```
const mapI = R.addIndex(R.map);
const mapAddIndexedProp = R.curry((key, fn) => mapI(R.pipe(R.flip(R.assoc(key)), fn)));
const mapAddKeyProp = mapAddIndexedProp('key');
```

But, seeing as what I really want is a function that accepts a string and a function, it seems like there ought to be a way to do something like:

```
const mapAddIndexedProp = mapI(R.pipe(R.flip(R.assoc(<arg1>)), <arg2>));
```

but I can't figure out how that'd work. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Or, highly likely, there's a cleaner way to do this with something like "over" or transduce. Thanks!

Comment: Do you wish to transform a list such as `[{first: 'Alice', last: 'Jones'}, {first: 'Bob', last: 'Smith'}]` into something like `[{first: 'Alice', last: 'Jones', fullName: 'Alice Jones'}, {first: 'Bob', last: 'Smith', fullName: 'Bob Smith'}]`?

Comment: that could be the end goal of the final function, as @Scott Sauyet has below in addFullNames, but the idea is to abstract the adding of a key to an object as part of the map transform and preceding the function that would be called on this new map function. Still not that clear, but essentially this would enable calling newMapWithKey(someFn, [{...},{...}]). In the example I gave, calling mapAddKeyProp(someFn, [{...}, {...}]) will add [{ key: 0 ...}, { key: 1 ...}] to each object before passing to someFn, which might need to use that key.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is quite straightforward to do if you don't try to insist on making it points-free:

```
const addKey = R.curry((key, fn, vals) => 
    R.map(obj => 
        R.assoc(key, fn(obj), obj), vals));
```

If you do really want the index as well, you could expand it to this:

```
const addKey2 = R.curry((key, fn, vals) => 
    R.addIndex(R.map)((obj, idx) => 
        R.assoc(key, fn(obj, idx), obj), vals));
```

You could use is like this:

```
const addFullNames = addKey('fullName', person => 
    `${person.first} ${person.last}`
);

const initials = person => R.head(person.first) + R.head(person.last);
const  addIds = addKey2('id', (person, idx) => `${initials(person)}_${idx}`)

var people = [
    {first: 'Wilma', last: 'Flintstone'}, 
    {first: 'Betty', last: 'Rubble'}
];

addFullNames(people); //=>
// [
//     {first: 'Wilma', last: 'Flintstone', fullName: 'Wilma Flintstone'}, 
//     {first: 'Betty', last: 'Rubble', fullName: 'Betty Rubble'}
// ];

addIds(people); //=>
// [
//     {first: 'Wilma', last: 'Flintstone', id: 'WF_0'}, 
//     {first: 'Betty', last: 'Rubble', id: 'BR_1'}
// ];
```

I'm sure there is a way to make this points-free.  But I'm also pretty sure that it would be significantly less elegant looking.

Comment: yep, that does the trick, and cleaner without the pipe and flip, which help it to be closer to being points-free while definitely sacrificing readability. Also 'points-free' was the word I was thinking of. Thanks, that's actually the first time I've heard it and what I was trying to get to with the function. I was hoping Ramda might have a way of dictating how arguments are applied, (some combination of R.__ and R.nthArg or something...) to achieve that points-free ideal here, but it probably isn't worth it in this case. Thanks!

Comment: If you still have a moment, I think making this pointfree has some similarity to an answer you gave here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29617142/how-to-rewrite-this-in-terms-of-r-compose. The code there now executes with an error "first argument to __arity must be non-negative integer no greater than 10". Any chance you could help me understand that code/error and perhaps further my silly quest here for a pointsfree implementation?

Comment: here's the code I'm referring to: // take :: Number -> Object -> Object
var take = R.converge(
    R.pick, 
    R.useWith(R.take, R.identity, R.keys), 
    R.nthArg(1)
);

Comment: I updated that answer to note the [recent changes](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/issues/1436) to `converge` and `useWith` that mean slightly revising the function.